# ArcPy While loop not ending

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.6

I've created a script that creates a buffer inside of a polygon. I want it to be an  ArcPy script that can run in ArcCatalog. However, it contains a while loop that won't close when run through ArcCatalog.

```
# import system modules 
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

# Overwrite pre-existing files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

class creBuffers(object):

    def __init__(self, inFile, outPath, outFile, buffCount):
        self.inFile = inFile
        self.outFile = outFile
        self.outPath = outPath
        self.buffCount = buffCount

    def createBuffers(self):
        cnt = 1
        bdt = 0
        while cnt <= self.buffCount:
            bdt = bdt - 500
            # Buffer areas of impact around major roads
            roads = self.inFile
            outer = os.path.join(self.outPath, self.outFile + "a_" + str(bdt * (-1)))
            roadsBuffer = outer
            distance = bdt
            sideType = "OUTSIDE_ONLY"
            endType = "ROUND"
            dissolveType = "NONE"
            arcpy.Buffer_analysis(roads, roadsBuffer, distance, sideType, endType, dissolveType)
            cnt = cnt + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    inFile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    outFile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
    outPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    buffCount = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

    scope = creBuffers(inFile, outPath, outFile, buffCount)

    scope.createBuffers()
```

The tool params are:

- Input File: Shapefile
- Output Path: Workspace
- Output File: Any Value
- Number of Buffers: Long

The tool creates the outputs fine but the while loop never closes and thus it creates too many outputs (an infinite amount, seemingly). The same script works as a standalone script

```
# import system modules 
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Overwrite pre-existing files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

class creBuffers(object):

    def __init__(self, inFile, outPath, outFile, buffCount):
        self.inFile = inFile
        self.outFile = outFile
        self.outPath = outPath
        self.buffCount = buffCount

    def createBuffers(self):
        cnt = 1
        bdt = 0
        while cnt <= self.buffCount:
            bdt = bdt - 500
            # Buffer areas of impact around major roads
            roads = self.inFile
            roadsBuffer = self.outPath + "\\" + self.outFile + "_" + str(bdt * (-1))
            distance = bdt
            sideType = "OUTSIDE_ONLY"
            endType = "ROUND"
            dissolveType = "NONE"
            arcpy.Buffer_analysis(roads, roadsBuffer, distance, sideType, endType, dissolveType)
            cnt += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Validate input
    while True:
        # Ask for the users input & validate
        try:
            inFile = raw_input("Type the path to and name of the input file: ")
        # Is the input a number? Validate
        except:
            print("Sorry, that is not a valid filename and path")
            # Invalid input received. Return loop
            continue
        # Is the number either 1 or 2? Validate
        if len(inFile) < 1:
            # Tell the user that this input is mandatory
            print("Sorry, the input must be at least one character long")
            continue
        # If user inputs 1 or 2: break the loop
        else:
            # Valid input
            break

    # Validate input
    while True:
        # Ask for the users input & validate
        try:
            outPath = raw_input("Type the path to the output FGDB: ")
        # Is the input a number? Validate
        except:
            print("Sorry, that is not a valid filename and path")
            # Invalid input received. Return loop
            continue
        # Is the number either 1 or 2? Validate
        if len(outPath) < 1:
            # Tell the user that this input is mandatory
            print("Sorry, the output must be at least one character long")
            continue
        # If user inputs 1 or 2: break the loop
        else:
            # Valid input
            break

    # Validate input
    while True:
        # Ask for the users input & validate
        try:
            outFile = raw_input("Type the name of the output file: ")
        # Is the input a number? Validate
        except:
            print("Sorry, that is not a valid filename and path")
            # Invalid input received. Return loop
            continue
        # Is the number either 1 or 2? Validate
        if len(outFile) < 1:
            # Tell the user that this input is mandatory
            print("Sorry, the output must be at least one character long")
            continue
        # If user inputs 1 or 2: break the loop
        else:
            # Valid input
            break

    # Validate input
    while True:
        # Ask for the users input & validate
        try:
            buffCount = input("Type the number (whole) of buffers you want to add: ")
        # Is the input a number? Validate
        except:
            print("Sorry, that is not a valid whole number")
            # Invalid input received. Return loop
            continue
        # If user inputs 1 or 2: break the loop
        else:
            # Valid input
            break

    scope = creBuffers(inFile, outPath, outFile, buffCount)

    scope.createBuffers()
```

I was just wondering if anyone else has had this problem and if they found a way to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`buffCount` looks to be a string, you need to convert that to an integer

Comment: Yep. I replaced `while cnt <= self.buffCount:` with `while cnt <= int(self.buffCount):` and it worked. I don't know how I didn't think of this. I either need more or less coffee today... not sure which.